# JMap with JVM Debugging Disabled

Tags: java, debugging, memory-leaks

Can I use jmap to create a java memory heap on a JVM which was started with debugging disabled? If so, how?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `jmap` you just need a JVMID, which is the process identifier of the JVM you want to dump.

First use `jps` to get the JVMID.
Then use `jmap` to dump the heap to a file.

Example:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin <JVMID>
```

Comment: You need to run jmap as the user running thejava app.  Note that running as root is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

(You know about visualvm and that it can connect to a running Java process?  Requires Sun Java 6)